# Collection with custom data not filtering

Tags: collection, filter, collection-filtering, custom-collection

Hi guys i have a collection in which i add custom data to. I am then trying to filter the collection by one of the original fields but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my collection building code:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order',
    'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.magento_order_entity_id',
    array('increment_id')
);

foreach($collection->getItems() as $item){
    $status = $this->getState($item->getId());
    $item->addData(array('response_state' => $status));
 }

return $collection;
```

This builds the collection successfully but when i try to use addFieldToFilter() to the collection it doesn't filter at all.

Here is the filter code:

`->addFieldToFilter('is_successful', array('eq' => $value));`

Anyone know why and how i can get this to work? Cheers

Comment: Try using `$item->setResponseState($status)` and `->addFieldToFilter('is_successful', $value)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Where exactly are you trying to use addFieldToFilter, also are you sure you shouldn't use addAttributeToFilter? Finally take a look at the query that is generated doing this.

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

**addAttributeToFilter()** is used to filter EAV collections.

**addFieldToFilter()** is used to filter Non-EAV collections.

Check here for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8581/5913